# tsc failed to build a single .vue file

Tags: typescript, vue.js, build, module, tsc

I'm creating a package that is exporting different code in different languages. Currently I want to export a `.vue` file. I have a `index.ts` file where I import my `.vue` file. I try to do that in the following way:

```
import Button from './Button.vue'

export default Button
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "build:clean": "rm -rf dist",
  "build:types": "tsc --declaration --emitDeclarationOnly --outDir ./dist/types",
  "build:source": "tsc --outDir ./dist/esm",
  "build": "npm run build:clean; npm run build:types; npm run build:source",
},
```

When running `build:source` I run into the following error:

```
src/vue/index.ts:2:23 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './Button.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.

import Button from './Button.vue'
```

Comment: Can you post your tsconfig.json?